# Remove Duplicates from Json file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, duplicates

I have a json file like below (test.json). I am unsuccessfully trying to parse the test array and remove duplicates of any "name" below

```
      {
    "test": [{
            "name": "jeb",
            "occupation": "teacher"
        },

        {
            "name": "jeb",
            "occupation": "writer"
        },
        {
            "name": "bob",
            "occupation": "skydiver"
        }

    ]
}
```

So far, my code is the following:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var i;
        var test= myObj.test.length;

        for (i=0; i<=myObj.test.length; i++) {
          var name = myObj.test[i].name;
          var occupation = myObj.test[i].occupation;
          console.log(name + " and " + occupation)

        }
      }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and it prints out:

```
jeb and teacher
jeb and writer
bob and skydiver
```

I would like the end result to be be:

```
jeb and teacher, writer
bob and skydiver
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be best to `reduce` into an object indexed by `name`, whose value is an array of occupations, and then once the object is created, you can iterate over it and print the occupations of each name:

```js
const obj = {
  "test": [{
    "name": "jeb",
    "occupation": "teacher"
  },{
    "name": "jeb",
    "occupation": "writer"
  },{
    "name": "bob",
    "occupation": "skydiver"
  }]
};

const namesByOccupation = obj.test.reduce((a, { name, occupation }) => {
  if (!a[name]) a[name] = [];
  a[name].push(occupation);
  return a;
}, {});
Object.entries(namesByOccupation).forEach(([name, occupations]) => {
  console.log(name + ' and ' + occupations.join(', '));
});
```